# Generic storage for functions and their attributes as tuple

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, stdtuple

I have a task to save "calls" to some free functions along with their params. This "calls" are filtered and applied later with `std::apply(func, tuple);`

For now I have come to the following abstraction:

```
class ... {
public:
   using E2Func = std::function<void(uint32_t, uint32_t)>;
   using E1F1Func = std::function<void(uint32_t, float)>;

   void SomeFunc(uint32_t x, uint32_t y) { CommonNamedState(__func__, SomeFuncImpl, x, y); }
   void SomeFunc2(uint32_t x, float y) { CommonNamedState(__func__, SomeFunc2Impl, x, y); }
   //more functions with different params (number of params, type of params)

   void CommonNamedState(const char* func, E2Func&& f, uint32_t v1, uint32_t v2) {
        const auto argsTuple = std::make_tuple(v1, v2);
        e2States[hashString(func)] = std::make_pair(f, argsTuple);
    }
   void CommonNamedState(const char* func, E1F1Func&& f, uint32_t v1, float v2) {
        const auto argsTuple = std::make_tuple(v1, v2);
        e1f1States[hashString(func)] = std::make_pair(f, argsTuple);
    }
   //more overloaded CommonNamedState() for each combination of argument numbers and params
public:
   void ApplyAll() {
       for (const auto& [hash, funcArgs] : e2States) {
           if (/* some_saved_state_has_same_hash */) {
                if (some_saved_state[hash].second != funcArgs.second) //check if arguments (as tuples) are different
                    std::apply(funcArgs.first, funcArgs.second);

           }
       }

       for (const auto& [hash, funcArgs] : e1f1States) {
           if (/* some_saved_state_has_same_hash */) {
                if (some_saved_state[hash].second != funcArgs.second) //check if arguments (as tuples) are different
                    std::apply(funcArgs.first, funcArgs.second);

           }
       }
       //roughly same for other *States map
   };
private:
   std::unordered_map<uint32_t, std::pair<E2Func, std::tuple<uint32_t, uint32_t >>> e2States;
   std::unordered_map<uint32_t, std::pair<E1F1Func, std::tuple<uint32_t, float >>> e1f1States;
   //more unordered_map's for each combination of argument numbers and params

};
```

It however suffers from one fundamental flaw: with more function like `SomeFunc()` I need to:

- manually define `std::function` type covering the specific arguments of a "captured function",
- manually define another std::unordered_map<> in case the "captured function" has number & types of arguments combination never seen prior
- manually create `CommonNamedState()` overloaded implementation packing incoming arguments into tuple and storing them into the unordered map.
- On the call side (not listed in the example) I need to manually specify traversal over each std::unordered_map content

All of this requires a lot of boilerplate code and it's not hard to make a mistake somewhere. I wonder if c++17 allows for any better solution that wouldn't require so much manual code.

Comment: I don't need to call stuff asynchronously. Just capture functions along with their arguments and call it later. But while I was looking at `std::packaged_task` semantics, I stumbled upon std::bind() that can capture arguments without any need for tuples. Looks like one of the solutions.

Comment: Actually no it's seem to be impossible to do what I aim for with `std::bind`, because captured function invocation is conditional to certain comparison of argument tuples and since std::bind doesn't expose captured arguments they can't be used for comparison

Comment: @lhog I'm not sure what are you trying to archieve, but you can make your own function object that contains necessary parameter values and std::function callback. It doesn't have to be std::bind. Or just accept tuple directly in E2Func..

Comment: If I accept tuple in `E2Func` it won't save me from the necessity to create new types similar to `E2Func` in case tuple will have different number and types of parameters. However I'm interested in _make your own function object_. Can you provide some example?

Comment: @lhog: Will these functions always return `void`? It isn't strictly necessary, but it could help.

Comment: @lhog: "*`e2States[hashString(func)]`*" This is not how you make a hashtable. You're supposed to store the strings as the keys, and the hash table will automatically hash them into buckets. But the hashtable needs the original strings so that it can check for collisions.

Comment: Is there a reason why a straightforward type erasure won't work? Something like this: `using callback = std::function<void()>; std::unordered_map<std::string, callback> states; states["SomeFunc"] = [=]() {SomeFuncImpl(v1, v2);};` When you need to call the function, just do `states["SomeFunc"]();` - arguments are already baked into the lambda and won't need to be stored separately.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik this is what I was trying to do roughly with std::bind, but unfortunately I need access to the actual values of `v1` and `v2` when I do `states["SomeFunc"]();` The actual decision whether to execute `SomeFunc` depends on the values of v1/v2 as they are compared to some other values prior to the execution.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thanks for pointing it out. Collisions are possible indeed, but I'm only dealing with around ~50 functions (it's a class to hold OpenGL FFP state, which you are very familiar with), so chances of collisions are not very high. `hashString()` calculates hash in the compile time from `__func__`, so it' beneficial to do from perf perspective. I have special test that `__func__` names I use don't collide into the same hash.

Comment: Show the calling code, complete with the "compared to other values" part. In other words, prepare a [mcve]. It's difficult to propose solutions without knowing the intended use case. How does this calling code deal with functions having different signatures?

Comment: I've extended example a little bit.
@NicolBolas yes all functions return void. Calls encapsulate `glBlendFunc` and alike.